# JavaScript RegEx, zero-length match with OR (look ahead and behind, maybe)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this regex `/\b\d\b/`, to simply match a single digit word.

Now I would like to add the underscore character as an alternative to a word boundary, so I would like to match the digit in `"_1_"` as well, while keeping the underscore as a zero-length match (as in \b, so I don't want the _ in the match).

I am in a case were using capturing groups will not be ideal.

I tried some positive look ahead/behind tricks, the look ahead seems to work, while the look behind didn't. Tried doing optional look ahead/behind, and doing something like `_|\b`, but I couldn't find an ideal solution for this.

Being not very knowledgeable in advanced RegEx tricks, I thought I'd ask before doing this with 2 RegExes :)

This is to be executed in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

`(?<=\b|_)\d(?=\b|_)`

```
(?<=    # Positive look-behind
\b      # Word boundary
|       # Or
_       # Underscore
)       # End group
\d      # Digit
(?=     # Positive look-ahead
\b|_)   # Word boundary or underscore
```

It will match your single digit, and will use either word boundaries (`\b`) or underscores (`_`) to match.

This is zero-length, so it won't group out the digit it matches.

[Play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?31e8d).

Comment: This will still include the underscores in the match result. I would like the underscores to be a zero-length optional match

Comment: @SamerAbukhait You're right, I've edited it so that it doesn't include the underscores.

Comment: That's the RegEx I tried actually, but I get invalid regex error with it. I tried in in Chrome, Node and even Ruby 1.9. The look-ahead part of it works, but the look-behind does not

Comment: @SamerAbukhait Yep, did some research and it looks like JS doesn't support look-behinds. I'll do some research and see if it can be mimicked.

Comment: Could you please edit the answer and write that it is not ready to use yet. From http://v8project.blogspot.de/2016/02/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html  : `You can already experiment with lookbehind assertions by running V8 version 4.9 or later with --harmony, or by enabling experimental JavaScript features (use about:flags) in Chrome from version 49 onwards.`

Answer (score 1):

Since look-behinds don't work in JS, you can match just for your main regex, in your case `\d`, and then manually check the boundaries.

```
const manualBoundaries = /\d/g
const matches = [];
while ((match = manualBoundaries.exec(str)) !== null) {
  const m = match[0]
  const i = match.index
  if ((i == 0 || str[i - 1].match(/(\W|_)/)) &&
      (i + m.length == str.length || str[i + m.length].match(/(\W|_)/)))
    matches.push(m)
}
```

Or more concisely, with a fake replace

```
const matches = [];
str.replace(manualBoundaries, (m, i) => {
    if ((i == 0 || str[i - 1].match(/(\W|_)/)) &&
        (i + m.length == str.length || str[i + m.length].match(/(\W|_)/)))
      matches.push(m);
});
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/djjeck/mg2gzpf1/